# Replacing all entries in one column by according elements in the rows using a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
A B
x 5.9027.5276
y 656.344872.0
z 78.954.23
```

What I want to reach is to replace the string entries in column `B` by floats of the first four numbers of the entries of column `B` as decimal numbers at the second position.

Therefore, I wrote the following code:

```
for entry in df['B']:
    entry = re.search(r'((\d\.?){1,4})', entry).group().replace(".","")
    df['B'] = entry[:1] + '.' + entry[1:]
    
df['B'] = df['B'].astype(float)
```

It almost does what I want but it replaces all the entries in `B` with the float value of the first row. Instead, I would like to replace the entries with the according float value of each row.

How could I do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the relevant pandas string functions:

```
df['B'] = df['B'].str.extract('((\d\.?){1,4})')[0].str.replace(r'\.', '')
df['B'] = df['B'].str[:1] + '.' + df['B'].str[1:]
df['B'] = df['B'].astype(float)

print(df)
   A      B
0  x  5.902
1  y  6.563
2  z  7.895
```

Answer (score 2):

You might encase your operation in function and then use `.apply` i.e.:

```
import re
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['x','y','z'],'B':['5.9027.5276','656.344872.0','78.954.23']})
def func(entry):
    entry = re.search(r'((\d\.?){1,4})', entry).group().replace(".","")
    return entry[:1] + '.' + entry[1:]
df['B'] = df['B'].apply(func)
df['B'] = df['B'].astype(float)
print(df)
```

output:

```
   A      B
0  x  5.902
1  y  6.563
2  z  7.895
```